# Js array to CSV add column headings

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here is the code which generates a `CSV` from array, Hard coded values gives proper column Headings and data in rows. I am adding data using a loop but unable to understand how do I add column headings.

Here is the hard coded array to export csv

```js
var Results = [
  ["Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4"],
  ["Data", 50, 100, 500],
  ["Data", -100, 20, 100],
];

exportToCsv = function() {
  var CsvString = "";
  Results.forEach(function(RowItem, RowIndex) {
    RowItem.forEach(function(ColItem, ColIndex) {
      CsvString += ColItem + ',';
    });
    CsvString += "\r\n";
  });
  CsvString = "data:application/csv," + encodeURIComponent(CsvString);
 var x = document.createElement("A");
 x.setAttribute("href", CsvString );
 x.setAttribute("download","somedata.csv");
 document.body.appendChild(x);
 x.click();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="exportToCsv()">export to CSV</button>
```

Excel looks like this
[image]

How do I manage **col1 , col2 , col3** when I am inserting row values using a loop like this -

```
  for(let i=0;i<this.goalList.length;i++)
  {
    console.log(i,this.goalList)
  var Result = [
    [this.goalList[i]['name'],this.goalList[i]['desc'], this.goalList[i]['phno']]
  ];
  
  Results.push(Result);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you have as headers Col1,Col2,Col3;

```
function downloadCsv(){
var rows= [{'col1':10,'col2':10,'col3':10},{'col1':10,'col2':10,'col3':10}, 
    {'col1':10,'col2':10,'col3':10},{'col1':10,'col2':10,'col3':10}]
    var headers = "col1,col2,col3\n";
    rows.forEach((row)=>{
      var values = []
      Object.keys(row).forEach((key)=>{        
        if(Array.isArray(row[key])){
          var type = [];
          row[key].forEach(element => {
            type.push(element.name)
          });
          console.log(type)
          values.push("\"" + type.join() + "\"")
        }else{
          typeof(row[key]) == "string" ? values.push("\"" + row[key] + "\"") : (row[key] == null ? values.push("") : values.push(row[key].toString()))
        }
      });
      headers = headers + values.join(",") + "\n"
      
    })
      download('CSV', 'Payroll.csv', 'text/csv', headers)
    }
```

As you can see we have to know what are the "keys" of our JSON, in order to create them dynamically, we obtain the keys of the object and we loop them, and create the format of the csv that we want.

Working JsFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/36o8cryu/

Comment: I achieve adding 1 line after the for loop `Results.unshift(["Name", "Desc", "Phone", "Address"]);` , it worked, accepting your working answer, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can initialise your `Results` array to contain the headings.